# Update figure without saving

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using the PGF-backend for matplotlib, I am trying to modify the ticklabels of my logarithmic y-axis. I do not however know beforehand what my ticklabels will be, so I'd like to get the ticklabels with `ax.get_yticklabels()` and then modify the text of the labels (by removing a substring). The problem is, that the list returned by `get_yticklabels()` is only filled when issuing the `savefig('plot.pdf')` command.

Is there a function that updates the whole figure without actually saving it, so I can get to the labels? The `fig.canvas.draw()` function does not work as I would have expected. I am using matplotlib version 1.2.0 with Python 3.3.0 on Linux.

PS: The underlying problem is, that I can't get a sans-serif font for the labels on logarithmic plots with the PGF-backend, which I am pretty sure is a bug in the backend. Any solution to that would of course also be welcome and make my initial question obsolete.